# Select null rows if value not exists

Tags: sql, null, key, exists

I have the following table:

Messages

```
id | key   | msg
-------------------
1  | ABC   | text a 
2  | CDE   | text c
3  | CDE   | text d
4  | null  | text x
```

I want to select all values from the table if I have `key = X` or select all values with null (with `key = null`). Something like this:

A) Messages (`select ... where key = CDE`, key CDE exists)

```
id | key   | msg
-------------------
2  | CDE   | text c
3  | CDE   | text d
```

B) Messages (`select ... where key = XYZ`, key XYZ not exists)

```
id | key   | msg
-------------------
4  | null  | text x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `or`:

```
select t.*
from t
where key = ? or
      (key is null and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.key = ?)
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE Key = 'CDE' OR Key IS NULL
```

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE Key = 'CDE' 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE Key IS NULL
```